# Is it safe to replace a 120ns Flash memory with a 90ns part?

Tags: flash, eeprom, speed, non-volatile-memory, rom

Here is an old PLC board with a pair of [AM29F200AB-120SI](https://octopart.com/datasheet/am29f200at120ec-amd-10373306) SOP-44 256kB 5V flash chips.  One is unable to retain data, after nearly three decades in service.

[image: 1785-L80E/E Flash Issues]

These are very challenging to find today, but plenty of faster variants like -90 are available.  Question is, what are the chances that a faster variant will work?

Many EEPROMs can be replaced with faster ones and this seems to work about 85% of the time.  Is it the same likelihood for Flash?

Comment: Are you able to find the datasheet for both? (I haven't tried.) I would imagine making comparisons between them. Have you really experienced faster but otherwise compatible EEROM's not working 15% of the time? (I have had a lot of experience swapping out faster UV EPROMS and never had difficulties for many years doing so (old instrument that has been in use some 40 years now.) So if you have had failures, it might be worth trying to find out why.

Comment: Flash, like most memories are tested and graded in production. Some parts just happen to work better than others. So, your 90ns part is probably identical to a 120ns part but just that is tested better. My guess is a 90ns part will work just like a 120ns part. With those flash parts, the system has no way of finding out what the speed grade is, so will have a bus cycle to accommodate a 120ns part. If the replacement part was slower, then there would most likely be a problem.